# Trouble writing text after \lstinputlisting

Tags: formatting, listings

I am a new to LaTeX and I am having trouble writing text after using `\lstinputlisting`.

Here what I am trying to do:
I am writing some text in a subsection and then using the `\lstinputlisting` command to insert an R language output. The R output is displayed beautifully and there is no problems with that. But whatever text I write after the `\lstinputlisting` command gets displayed before the R language output. Here is my code snippet:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,8pt]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-.7in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-.7in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1.75in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.75in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.75in}

\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\chead{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy} 

\title{Title }
\author{ABC}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

 \section*{Exercise 1}
  This is Exercise 1

 \begin{enumerate}
 \item[(1.1)] Do this first
 \item[(1.2)] Then do this
 \end{enumerate}


 \section*{Solution 1}
  Steps for importing data in R\\
  {\color{blue}
   \textgreater \hspace{0.2cm}  qaz=read.table('qaz.txt') \\
   \textgreater \hspace{0.2cm} qaz \\
  }

 \lstinputlisting[float=h,frame=tb,caption=Socio Data,numbers=left]    {sociooutput1.txt}

This text should be displayed after the R output

\end{document}
```

And here is what I see as output. I would like to see the text "This text should be displayed after the R output" after the R output

[image: The PDF created]

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You have `floating` enabled, i.e. LaTeX puts the listing to some other place, where it thinks it fits better. Remove the `float=h` option and the listing should be placed at the position you want to appear it, but it may be too long.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Do you want to write up an answer?

Comment: @TeXnician: Done so. Thanks for reminding ;-)

Answer (score 4):

The usual problem with placing content from `figure` or `table` is that they are floating 'around', i.e. LaTeX looks for the 'best' place where it fits. This causes undesirable results occasionally.

Here `lstlisting` is enabled to float around as well with `float=h`, which might work but not in any case. Just remove `float=h` and the listing environment occurs at the place it is desired (i.e. before the relevant text)

(I changed the input file however, since I don't know `R` etc. and do not have the relevant `.txt` file at hand, see at the end of the post for a sample `.c` file)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,8pt]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-.7in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-.7in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1.75in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.75in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.75in}

\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\chead{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy} 

\title{Title }
\author{ABC}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

 \section*{Exercise 1}
  This is Exercise 1

 \begin{enumerate}
 \item[(1.1)] Do this first
 \item[(1.2)] Then do this
 \end{enumerate}


 \section*{Solution 1}
  Steps for importing data in R\\
  {\color{blue}
   \textgreater \hspace{0.2cm}  qaz=read.table('qaz.txt') \\
   \textgreater \hspace{0.2cm} qaz \\
  }

 \lstinputlisting[frame=tb,caption=Socio Data,numbers=left]{helloworldexample.c}% sociooutput1.txt

This text should be displayed after the R output

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is the file `helloworldexample.c` that is used in the solution above.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  printf("Hello World!\n");
  return(0);
}
```